# Postfix - hostname appearing in email address

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, hostname

I have a fresh install of postfix on Ubuntu 14.04 server but the test emails I have sent all include the hostname in the email address. I have searched and found quite a few people with the same problem but none of their solutions worked/applied to me. I have tried options from various tutorials but I don't seem to get the same results as they do.

My /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
mydomain = example.com    
myorigin = example.com
smtpd_banner = $mydomain ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no 
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = merlin.example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

My /etc/hosts file is:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
XX.XX.XX.XX     merlin.example.com merlin

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

An example received mail header is:

```
Delivered-To: xxx@gmail.com
Received: by 10.107.173.142 with SMTP id m14csp624755ioo;
Sun, 3 Apr 2016 01:12:36 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.66.101.35 with SMTP id fd3mr43641306pab.7.1459671156649;
Sun, 03 Apr 2016 01:12:36 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <user@merlin.example.com>
Received: from merlin.example.com (xxx-89-xx-64.xxx.xxx.xx.xx. [xxx.89.xx.64])
by mx.google.com with ESMTP id n69si18026934pfi.104.2016.04.03.01.12.36
for <xxx@gmail.com>;
Sun, 03 Apr 2016 01:12:36 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: xxx.89.xx.64 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of user@merlin.example.com) client-ip=xxx.89.xx.64;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
spf=neutral (google.com: xxx.89.xx.64 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of user@merlin.example.com) smtp.mailfrom=user@merlin.example.com
Received: by merlin.example.com (Postfix, from userid 1000)
id 02854601326; Sun,  3 Apr 2016 20:12:12 +1200 (NZST)
```

I can't see what is wrong in my setup and have changed as many options as I can think of based on looking at http://www.postfix.org/. I have restarted postfix after every change.

I would appreciate any suggestions :)

Comment: Your example received header does not include the From address, only the MAIL From/Return-Path address, but I'll suppose they are the same.

The address is set by the program that is sending the mail, your MUA. How did you send the mail? `echo test | mutt -- xxx@gmail.com`?

Comment: One initial comment from my side would be that after fiddling with oh-so-many options you should go back to a baseline at some point and find out which _combination of_ options gave the desired effect. E-mails seem to be sth trivial but an MTA is not.

For the rest I agree with Law29. Configure the email client.

Comment: Ah ok, I was sending using `mail -s "Test subject" xxx@gmail.com`. Adding '-aFrom:xxx@example.com' worked - doh! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Excerpt from [postfix help](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#myorigin):

**What domain name to use in outbound mail**

The *myorigin* parameter specifies the domain that appears in mail that is posted on this machine. The default is to use the local machine name, *$myhostname*, which defaults to the name of the machine. Unless you are running a really small site, you probably want to change that into *$mydomain*, which defaults to the parent domain of the machine name.

For the sake of consistency between sender and recipient addresses, *myorigin* also specifies the domain name that is appended to an unqualified recipient address.

Examples (specify only one of the following):

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
    myorigin = $myhostname (default: send mail as "user@$myhostname")
    myorigin = $mydomain   (probably desirable: "user@$mydomain")
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert with postfix by any means but I do not see a mydomain directive in your config.

My configs are setup like this:

`mydomain = example.com
myorigin = $mydomain`

Comment: Oops - cut and paste error - have edited it to show the mydomain setting. Have tried mydomain = /etc/mailname and setting it directly as in the code above.